# deleting spaces in XML

Tags: jquery, xml, arrays, space

this is XML, and i want to see like"thisisthecontentwhatiwant."
there are spaces in the sentence, and  the two sentences are sperated by "enter."
when i use the array, it recognizes every spaces even the space by enter.
what do I do to delete spaces in the array in Jquery?

`<list>
        <title name="symbol-B">1</title>
        <chr>this is the content
what i want</chr>`
  `</list>`

this is the jsfilddle

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "XMLFile1.xml",
    async: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('list').each(function () {

            obj = $(this).find("title");

            if (obj.text() == "1") {
                var charList1 = (obj.next().text());
                    alert(charList1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text` and `split` methods.

```
$('list chr').text().split(" ").join('');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aAdTA/

You can concatenate the results:

```
 var text = '';
 $(xml).find('list').each(function () {
        obj = $(this).find("title");
        if (obj.text() == "1") {
            text += " " + obj.next().text().split(" ").join('');
        }
 })
 alert(text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! one more, the two sentence show up two like when i use the enter in <chr> like thisisthecontent at first line and what i want at the second line. Is there  a way to see two sentence in one line??? i have to put the sentences at each line.

Comment: I put jsfiddle on my writing @undefined

Comment: @ undefined Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/aAdTA/5/ i can still see spaces in the sentence.

Comment: @ undefined i think first way you showed me is good for me. Thank you for helping me~! ^^